# AWS AutoScaling based on HTTP requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

So I've been trying to figure out how to set up AutoScaling using the difference in RequestCount from time A (x) to time B (y). 
So if ((y-x) >= 10000) add an instance 
 if ((y-x) <= -10000) remove an instance 
 
 So far I'm hoping to use the last scaling action as time A although I'm not 100% sure this is possible. I've been playing with monitoring SNS so at least there's a metric somewhere that knows a scaling action has occurred. 
 
 Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Do I understand correctly you are designing your own solution to this? Why? No one has ever done this before?

Comment: Maybe my google-fu is weak. As far as I can tell no one has done this and bothered to document it in a way accessible to the public.